# Backbone Collection: Remove a model and add action 'Remove' before posting to server

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I've been trying to implement a use-case where I've a collection of email list. Following is a JSON response retrieved from the backend:

```
{ "emails": [
{
  "action": null,
  "emailType": null,
  "emailAddress": "test@hello.com"
},
{
  "action": null,
  "emailType": "EML1",
  "emailAddress": "hello@world.com"
}]}
```

When deleting an email, I

```
this.collection.remove(this.emailModel);
```

All this does is removes the deleted model from the collection. Instead I'd like to not remove but add an action = "Delete" to this deleted model such that the UPDATE request payload becomes something like this:

```
{ "emails": [
{
  "action": null,
  "emailType": null,
  "emailAddress": "test@hello.com"
},
{
  "action": "Delete",
  "emailType": "EML1",
  "emailAddress": "hello@world.com"
}]}
```

Can anyone suggestme a way to go about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using the regular `set`?

Comment: Is your use case that you are trying to delete the email address from the client and the server?

Comment: @PeterWagener, Yes. I have to send a Delete status to the server that a particular email has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

For deleting model, instead of

```
this.collection.remove(this.emailModel);
```

Do

```
this.emailModel.destroy();
```

That'll send a `DELETE` request and remove the model from collection.

---

To answer your question:

You can do `this.emailModel.set("action","Delete");` and then call `.save()` on the model, which will send a `POST/UPDATE` request with the model data depending on the state of model. You can override models `sync` method to always send `POST` if your backend also doesn't support `UPDATE`. When the `save` is success, remove the model from collection at client side.  Ideally your backend should be restful for easy integration with backbone.

Comment: this is correct. But the backend logic is implemented such that it only checks for Action status, if Delete, then it'll delete that record.